# Увеличение значения счетчика в цикле

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, счетчики

Всем привет. Есть у меня блок со значением счетчика (может быть любое) подскажите плиз, можно ли как-то просто скриптом увеличивать значение на 1 в скрипте, срабатывающему по ajax?

```
<span class="shop-icon">
    <span class="count">1</span>
</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function( $ ) {
       ( document ).on( 'click', '.single_add_to_cart_button', function() {
       });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: А что вы хотели сделать в приведенном JavaScript коде? И причем тут AJAX?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Потому что AJAX классный. Стоит его использовать всегда и везде)

Comment: @PeterOlson это хорошо, что AJAX классный, но он не имеет отношения к вопросу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно без AJAX увеличивать значение счетчика, вот просто так:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', '.single_add_to_cart_button', function() {
    $counter = $(".count");
    $counter.text(+$counter.text() + 1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="shop-icon">
    <span class="count">1</span>
</span><br>
<button class="single_add_to_cart_button">Увеличить значение счетчика</button>
```

Comment: да, спасибо, я уже тоже решил, только сделал это немного правильнее - текст нужно принудительно к int приводить и исключить бесконечность, ато javascript умеет удивлять в очевидных вещах: `$(".shop-icon .count").text(Math.max(parseInt($(".shop-icon .count").text()) + 1));`

Comment: @Вася `parseInt` понял, если например хотите конвертировать `1.43` на `1`, но зачем `Math.max`? Там ведь только одно число.

Comment: чтобы ограничить бесконечность - не?

Comment: @Вася `Math.max` возвращает самое большое число в группе, например, `Math.max(1, 5, 2, 92, 4)===92`.

Comment: а, ну ок - я думал у него другое назначение

Comment: кстати, прикол, а у меня без Math.max то не работает.. а с ним все гуд

Comment: @Вася Что не работает с `.text(parseInt($(".count").text()) + 1)`?

Comment: уже и math не работает - возможно, скрипты конфликтуют

Comment: @Вася В коде Вы написали math или Math? Только Math работает.

Comment: с большой буквы. у меня счет начинается с 0 - может в этом дело?

Comment: оказывается, скрипт просто не до конца отрабатывал - я не сразу это обнаружил .вопрос снят